# How to query for TaskRelation contacts from Task?

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to query for all the taskRelation (for contacts only for now) Ids from the specific Task id and then add them in List(called ContactIds). 
When I tried `taskcontacts.TaskRelations` it kept throwing error:

> Variable does not exist: TaskRelation.

```
List<Task> taskContacts = [SELECT Id, Subject, (SELECT RelationId, Relation.Name from TaskRelations) FROM Task WHERE id in:tks];
    //List<Task> taskContacts = [SELECT RelationId, Relation.Name, Task.id, Task.Subject from TaskRelation WHERE id in:tks];
    //System.debug('Print Task Contacts: ' + taskContacts.TaskRelations);
    List
    System.debug('Print Task Contacts: ' + taskContacts);


 // Here I am trying to loop through an above query to find all contacts and add all the contacts to contact ids.

   for(Task ti: taskContacts)
   {
    for(TaskRelation tRel: taskContacts.TaskRelations) // does not work
    {
       System.debug('Print Task Contacts: ' + tRel); // does not work
       if (t.Rel.size> 0){                    // checking if size is greater than 0 
         ContactIds.add(tRel.id);             // then add in contactId list

        }  
    }

}
       /* then from here use the ContactId to update each contact's field */
```

Comment: you should accept adrian's answer and then pose a new question for the new issue with the corrected code

Comment: Will do, Cropredy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to reference the related list of your entire collection, rather than your single record:

```
for(Task ti: taskContacts)
{
    for(TaskRelation tRel: taskContacts.TaskRelations)
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ problem here
```

You should reference `ti` instead of `taskContacts` in your second loop declaration.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. I will try and update here.

Comment: That worked !!! Thank you Adrian